# How to set build Id from artificat in pipeline deployment name?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Still migrating from classic to yaml pipeline. Hope you can give me some advices on the following scenario. 
I have unique repository and two yml files:

- azurepipelines_build.yml: which basically publish artifact
- azurepipelines_deploy.yml: which basically download previous artifact and do stuff.
  These 2 pipelines are sequential.

My azurepipelines_build.yml looks this:

```
trigger:
  - main

name: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Build.BuildId)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)
```

And with that i can see easily my *buildId* updated everytime i start this pipeline.

Now my azurepipelines_deploy.yml looks this:

```
trigger:
  - none

resources:
 pipelines:
   - pipeline: myproject-build
     source: myproject-build
     trigger:
      branches:
        - '*'
name: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(resources.pipeline.myproject-build.runID)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)
...
...
   steps:
     - script: |
       echo "Checking build id $(resources.pipeline.myproject-build.runID)"
```

I do confirm that `echo "Checking build id $(resources.pipeline.myproject-build.runID)"`  works and i get correct build Id reference.

Unfortunately for the **name** I do not have `$(resources.pipeline.myproject-build.runID)` as expected. I wonder if it is possible and requires your advice. It is something possible ?

Thx 
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is a special field to set run number. Not everything is allowed here. For expressions you can [have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#expressions)

> If you use an expression to set the build number, you can't use some tokens because their values aren't set at the time expressions are evaluated. These tokens include $(Build.BuildId), $(Build.BuildURL), and $(Build.BuildNumber).

`resources.pipeline.myproject-build.runID` is empty at a time of evaluation of name expressions and this is not possible to overcome this, because [Pipeline resource metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines)

> In each run, the metadata for a pipeline resource is available to all jobs as the following predefined variables. These variables are available to your pipeline at runtime, and therefore can't be used in template expressions, which are evaluated at pipeline compile time.

Comment: Thx madej for your confirmation